# How to fix dates in a data frame that have mixed characters

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I imported a data set through openxlsx into a data frame.  The spreadsheet has various fields including several date fields.  In these date fields are some characters -- specifically "A" and "*".  So my data set looks like this:

A  |  43998

B  |  44316

C  |  44284

D  |  11-Mar-19 A

E  |  44323

F  |  29-Jul-20*

I'm using several date fields, and am looking for a way to swiftly fix them (as opposed to filtering, str_replacing, then changing data types, and rbind-ing back).

I've been looking at lubridate, but I can't find a way when the dates come through so differently.

```
library(openxlsx)
library(lubridate)

data <- read.xlsx(file)
data2 <- data %>% mutate(fixed_date1 = ifelse(str_detect(date1,
   " A")==TRUE,as.Date(date1, guess_formats(date1,
   "dmy")),as.Date(as.numeric(date1)-2,origin = "1900-01-01")))
```

This still doesn't account for the asterisks floating in there, which I think I'll have to build a str_detect(date1, "\\*") line into the ifelse statement...

I just hope to find a way to apply it to each of the columns in one swipe.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try with `parse_date_time` from `lubridate` or `anydate` from `anytime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it with a couple lines:

```
df$date1 <- str_replace_all(df$date1, " A", "")
df$date1 <- str_replace_all(df$date1, "\\*", "")
df <- df %>% mutate(fixed_date1 = ifelse(str_detect(date1, "-") == TRUE, as.Date(date1,
      "%d-%b-%y"), as.Date(as.numeric(date1)-2, origin = "1900-01-01")))
```

So I did a find and replace all the special characters, then did the date conversion depending on if it had a "-" in it or not.

There's probably an easier way, but this works for me.

Comment: I should also say that I have to change the variable to date as well, but it seemed to work.